# How to maintain a downloading progress of list view item in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using ListView that contains item template to show book information with download button ( Contains Image of book, Title, Author and button to download book).

Need to show download progress while click download button of each book. I have managed progress value in separate class and used that separate class object to maintain progress of each book in collection. Like below,

[image]

When scrolling the page download progress value for downloading books becomes null. For example in the above screenshot, download progress value shown null when scroll the view. Could you please suggest on this?

Comment: The row items are reused by the android system when you scroll up or down to save memory. Do you mind to make your `ProgressBar` invisible when scrolling?

Comment: Already set isvisible property based on download button. Once, download button clicked then set IsDownloadStarted as true based on this visibility set for progress bar when scrolling.

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Any update?

Comment: Thanks for your update. I have bind each properties into template visibility and used converter to process it. It working fine.

Comment: Then if you find my answer helpful, could you please mark it?

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking that you may set a scroll listener to your listview, and if the listview is being scrolled, make your ProgressBar gone.

But if you don't want to do this, you may try implement a “ViewHolder” design pattern, this can possibly solve your issue. Because

> A ViewHolder object stores each of the component views inside the tag field of the Layout, so you can immediately access them without the need to look them up repeatedly.

Please refer to [Tips & Tricks for Highly Performing Android ListViews](https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-highly-performant-smooth-scrolling-android-listviews/) to implement the “ViewHolder” design pattern for your `ListView` and don't forget to set tag to each item view.